# Unable to send emails from Mailgun after setting up new domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mailgun

I added a new domain to mailgun and also successfully verified it but I am unable to send emails from that domain. I am trying to use the mailgun API to send the emails. I can send emails from the Mailgun sandbox domain but not from my own domain.

I have done the following in my code:

```
var api_key = 'api-key-here';
var domain = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/MY-DOMAIN-NAME.com';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});
```

Also within my user signup function I have the following:

```
var data = {
                from: 'Excited User <DoNotReply@MY-DOMAIN-NAME.com>',
                to: email,
                subject: ' Account Verification',
                text: 'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' + 'http://' + req.headers.host + '/verify/' + token + '\n\n'
           };

                 mailgun.messages().send(data, function(error, body) {
                      console.log("sending email ")
                 });
```

It does not send an email and nothing shows up in the domain logs as well.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`domain` should be just `MY-DOMAIN-NAME.com`, not `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/MY-DOMAIN-NAME.com`, because `mailgun-js` handles that internally.